# Entity Framework Core 2.2.4 error on insert items with 1:n relation - best solution

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, xamarin.android

I have a SQL Server database as the web service backend and a local SQLite database at the mobile frontend.

Both use EF Core 2.2.4 with *TpH* approach and share the majority of C# classes, but - of course - the backend classes have more properties due to administrational things to take care of. To model the differences, conditional attributes and fluent API is used (see code below).

Main idea is that the db content is created at the backend and an excerpt is then stored in the frontend db.

At the very end (and simplified), the local db should store only a list of units.

Each unit contains a list of exercises (n:m).

Exercises are derived from an abstract class, and some exercise types can contain a list of required tools (1:n) which are stored in an extra table.

Each exercise is unique, so that I can use its primary key for the n:m unit-exercise relation.

On the other hand a tool may be referenced by more than one exercises, which causes troubles on adding units with exercises to the local frontend database.

The problem is, that the exercise-tools 1:n mapping also uses the primary key of the tool, because that's how the backend creates it, and hence, if a primary key of a tool on the frontend already exists, a frontend db `Add()` call fails with

> SQLite Error 19: 'UNIQUE constraint failed: Tool.Id'

So, the question is: what is the simplest way to (re)design the model for the frontend, so that I only insert a list of units generated by the backend

1. without getting an error
2. without doing a lot of database things by hand, cause that's what EF should do for me

Here comes the example code

```
namespace Test
{
#if FRONTEND
    [Table("TestUnit")]
#endif      
    public class TestUnit
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; } // Use values from backend

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<TestExerciseSequence> ExerciseSequences { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestExerciseSequence
    {
        public Guid UnitId { get; set; }
        public TestUnit Unit { get; set; }

        public Guid ExerciseId { get; set; }
        public TestExercise Exercise { get; set; }
    }


#if FRONTEND
    [Table("TestExercise")]
#endif
    public abstract class TestExercise
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Discriminator { get; set; }

        public List<TestExerciseSequence> ExerciseSequences { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestExerciseType1 : TestExercise
    {
        public TestExerciseToolType ToolType { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestExerciseToolType
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<TestExerciseType1> ExerciseTypes { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestLocalDBContext : DbContext
    {
        // All locally stored units
        public DbSet<TestUnit> Units { get; set; }

        private const string databaseName = "sqlite.db";
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            string databasePath;
            switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
            {
                case Device.Android:
                    databasePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), databaseName);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException("Platform not supported");
            }
#if FRONTEND                        
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Filename={databasePath}")
                          .EnableDetailedErrors()
                          .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                          ;
#endif                                                  
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            // n : m relationship between 'Unit' to 'Exercise'
            modelBuilder.Entity<TestExerciseSequence>()
                .HasKey(us => new { us.UnitId, us.ExerciseId });

            modelBuilder.Entity<TestExerciseSequence>()
                .HasOne<TestUnit>(us => us.Unit)
                .WithMany(u => u.ExerciseSequences)
                .HasForeignKey(us => us.UnitId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<TestExerciseSequence>()
                .HasOne<TestExercise>(us => us.Exercise)
                .WithMany(e => e.ExerciseSequences)
                .HasForeignKey(us => us.ExerciseId);

#if FRONTEND                                
            // TestExerciseToolType causes troubles     
            modelBuilder.Entity<TestExerciseToolType>()
                .Property(c => c.Id)
                .ValueGeneratedNever();

            modelBuilder.Entity<TestExerciseToolType>()
                .HasIndex(c => c.Id)
                .IsUnique(true);
#endif

            // 1 : n relationship between 'TestExerciseType1' to 'TestExerciseToolType'
            modelBuilder.Entity<TestExerciseType1>()
                .HasOne<TestExerciseToolType>(etmt => etmt.ToolType)
                .WithMany(etmt => etmt.ExerciseTypes);

#if FRONTEND                                
            // Copied from above        
            modelBuilder.Entity<TestExerciseToolType>()
                .Property(c => c.Id)
                .ValueGeneratedNever();
            modelBuilder.Entity<TestExerciseToolType>()
                .HasIndex(c => c.Id)
                .IsUnique(true);
#endif

            // Table-per-Hierarchy for 'Exercise'
            modelBuilder.Entity<TestExercise>()
                .HasDiscriminator<string>("Discriminator")
                .HasValue<TestExerciseType1>("ExerciseTypeMovement")
                                ;

            modelBuilder.Entity<TestExercise>().Property("Discriminator").HasMaxLength(80);

            // Unit - ExerciseSequence
            modelBuilder.Entity<TestUnit>().HasMany(u => u.ExerciseSequences);
        }
    }
    public class TestDBHelper<T> where T : TestLocalDBContext
    {
        protected TestLocalDBContext CreateContext()
        {
            var dbContext = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
            dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
            dbContext.Database.Migrate();
            return dbContext;
        }

        public void AddUnit(TestUnit u)
        {
            using (var context = CreateContext())
            {
                context.Units.Add(u);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and test code

```
    private void DoTest()
    {
            var uId1 = Guid.NewGuid();
            var uId2 = Guid.NewGuid();

            var eId1 = Guid.NewGuid();
            var eId2 = Guid.NewGuid();
            var eId3 = Guid.NewGuid();
            var eId4 = Guid.NewGuid();

            var u1 = new TestUnit()
            {
                    Id = uId1,
                    Name = "Unit1",
                    ExerciseSequences = new List<TestExerciseSequence>()
                    {
                            new TestExerciseSequence()
                            {
                                    UnitId = uId1,
                                    ExerciseId = eId1,
                                    Exercise = new TestExerciseType1()
                                    {
                                            Id = eId1,
                                            Discriminator = "TestExerciseType1",
                                            Name = "E1",
                                            ToolType = new TestExerciseToolType()
                                            {
                                                    Id = 1,
                                                    Name = "M1"
                                            }
                                    }
                            },
                            new TestExerciseSequence()
                            {
                                    UnitId = uId1,
                                    ExerciseId = eId2,
                                    Exercise = new TestExerciseType1()
                                    {
                                            Id = eId2,
                                            Discriminator = "TestExerciseType1",
                                            Name = "E2",
                                            ToolType = new TestExerciseToolType()
                                            {
                                                    Id = 2,
                                                    Name = "M2"
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            };

            var u2 = new TestUnit()
            {
                    Id = uId2,
                    Name = "Unit2",
                    ExerciseSequences = new List<TestExerciseSequence>()
                    {
                            new TestExerciseSequence()
                            {
                                    UnitId = uId2,
                                    ExerciseId = eId3,
                                    Exercise = new TestExerciseType1()
                                    {
                                            Id = eId3,
                                            Discriminator = "TestExerciseType1",
                                            Name = "E3",
                                            ToolType = new TestExerciseToolType()
                                            {
                                                    Id = 3,
                                                    Name = "M3"
                                            }
                                    }
                            },
                            new TestExerciseSequence()
                            {
                                    UnitId = uId2,
                                    ExerciseId = eId4,
                                    Exercise = new TestExerciseType1()
                                    {
                                            Id = eId4,
                                            Discriminator = "TestExerciseType1",
                                            Name = "E4",
                                            ToolType = new TestExerciseToolType()
                                            {
                                                    Id = 1, // Exception!
                                                    Name = "M1"
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            };

            try
            {
                    var database = new TestDBHelper<TestLocalDBContext>();
                    database.AddUnit(u1);
                    database.AddUnit(u2); // Exception 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Error {ex.Message}");
            }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The easiest way would obviously be to let EF do the PK handling for you, you'd just have to rewrite your code to use references instead of actual seperate objects. If you are not willing to do that, the main issue is that you are splitting up a unit of work over multiple contexts; the second context has no idea you just opened another context and added exactly the same item it is going to insert. Either handle the DbContext instance yourself and/or remove the navigation property from the tree by either nulling it before calling .Add or attaching the entity and setting its state to added.

Comment: "Let EF do the PK handling for you" would mean, that on my local database I would have different PK values (guids) than on my backend database - is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

When working with entities, the context is the "owner" of entities. You can 'new' up an entity, but you have to respect that the context is expecting to be in control of the entity.

When you do something like:

```
var parent1 = new Parent
{
   ParentId = 1,
   Child = new Child
   {
      ChildId = 1,
   },
}
var parent2 = new Parent
{
   ParentId = 2,
   Child = new Child
   {
      ChildId = 1,
   }
}
context.Parents.Add(parent1);
context.Parents.Add(parent2);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Parent 1 will add successfully, but parent2 will fail. It fails because EF will essentially go through both cases and treat each parent's child as a new entity. When it encounters a "new" child on Parent 1 with ID = 1 then you get a PK violation.

If you set up your entities to use Identity columns you can avoid this error, but Parent 1 & 2's child reference will point to two different records with different generated IDs.

To avoid this, when setting up bulk data, create and associate your child entities first, then associate them to the parents. For example:

```
var child1 = new Child { ChildId = 1 };
var parent1 = new Parent 
{
  ParentId = 1,
  Child = child1
}
var parent2 = new Parent
{
  ParentId = 2,
  Child = child1
}
context.Parents.Add(parent1);
context.Parents.Add(parent2);
context.SaveChanges();
```

This way both parents reference the same child and as EF goes to persist each parent it will resolve the same child reference from the context.

The same goes for 1-to-many relationships:
`parent1.Children.Add(child1)`
rather than
`parent1.Children.Add(new Child { ChildId = 1 });`

If you want to create entities and set FK IDs rather than references, but return those entities to be consumed as normal entities (lazy loading references if necessary) then you should utilize `DbSet.Create()` rather than `new`.

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of the "ownership info".
So, to avoid these ownership issues, I have re-written my entity classes like described in 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities#handling-deletes

where I have my 
Unit entity class extended by a method

`void InsertUpdateOrDelete(DBContext context)
{
}
`
But - referencing to the question in the headline - this is a lot of code I need to write for each and every entity class.
Is there a more generic way - a better solution - to achieve this?

Comment: The first question would be "what do you want to test?" IMO there is no point testing that EF can persist data because EF is already tested and vetted. Unit tests should be satisfied by verifying that your business logic does what it is supposed to, and a mock of your persistence code (Repository etc.) gets called (or not) with appropriate parameters. For integration-style tests (real-like data state) I generally use pre-populated database backups. This lets me consider performance measuring against realistic data volume as well.

Comment: Ahh - sorry, the entity class names  'TestUnit' or 'Unit' are misleading, they have nothing to do with unit testing as part of the development life cycle. Actually, the 'units' are meant to be just like "course units" in school, which may contain "course exercises" which may require some tools.

The question still is, that - if I want to **mirror** an SQL Server database from the backend to an SQLite database on a mobile frontend, which contains 1:n relations, do I have to write code like `InsertUpdateOrDelete()` described in my prev. comment, or **is there a better solution?**

Comment: Ah, ok in context with the original description that makes sense now, I missed out on some of the question context. :) Replication is always painful. Have you considered something like https://ampliapps.com/sqlite-sync/ ?